# How can you create this flared look using CSS or if necessary SVG?

Tags: css, svg

[image: Here's what I'm trying to make]

Ideally I'd like to do this using CSS3, but would settle for SVG. I can make something quasy like this in CSS [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NCqww/42/) ...but border-radius didn't seem up to flaring out the curved lines like the image shows.

Basically I have a header div and am hoping to create this darker curved region at the top of it.

I'd greatly appreciate any help from any clever CSS gurus. Thanks!

Comment: You might not be satisfied with existing CSS solutions, but I do wish you luck.

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: You might be able to get this effect using the CSS triangles technique combined with rounded corners, but I'd probably go with images for simplicity.

Comment: i guess this will help you enouch solving your problem on your own: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it pretty close using the jsFiddle you started and changing up the border radius a bit.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryMathews/Q9Mrt/

using border radius you can define different lengths for the x and y axis. So I used

```
border-bottom-right-radius:40px 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius:40px 20px;
```

That gives it a length of 40 on the x axis and 20 on the y. Its not quite as sharp as your picture above but its pretty close. [more info](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)